# Setting up IE driver and FireFox driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I still didn´t find any way to setting up FireFox driver or IE driver.
For using Chrome driver, you will just easily write:

```
ChromeDriver driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"Chrome driver directory");
```

something like `ChromeDriver driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\");`and you can work with GC.
But for setting up FF driver I tried to use:

```
FirefoxDriver driverFF = new `FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"directory of gecko driver"));`
FirefoxDriver driverFF = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"c:\firefox"));
```

But the problem here is that will just open FF and immediately close without any other action.
There was a second way to use FF driver, but it wanted to navigate to Profile driver directory, but what they means with profile ?

For IE driver, I tried to use old way similar to GC, but it does´t work.

```
  InternetExplorerDriver driverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Driver");
```

Is there someone who can show me how to write the code or on which .exe navigates it?

I found helpers just for JAVA, but I need to use it in C#.
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937067/firefox-webdriver-opens-first-run-page-all-the-time, https://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/07/31/getting-started-using-selenium-2-0-webdriver-for-ie-in-visual-studio-c/

Answer (score 1):

I am using Nuget to install Selenium into my Visual Studio project, and with this I would just install ***`Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver`*** or ***`Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver`***.  I haven't used the FireFox driver, yet, but I would assume that this should work similar to the IEDriver.

I am using Specflow to assist me in my testing but I don't think it should matter much.

I add to my using statements the following line

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

The class that I create needs to implement the IDisposable interface so that I can create a disposal method and dispose of the driver itself or close the browser that is opened in the first step of the test.

In the first step (method) I create my new Driver

```
var ie = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

This will open the browser window.

then you run your tests or whatever

Then when everything is done it will call your new dispose method

```
public void Dispose()
{
    ie.Close();
    ie.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 2.53.0 is compatible up-to Firefox version 46.0 only.Once check your Firefox browser version.Currently running 48.0 FF version.

I given answer based on your statement.

**But the problem here is that will just open FF and immediately close without any other action.**

Update us if you have queries or issue resolved.

Comment: I have FF version 47.0 :/

Comment: Then selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar is won't work. Uninstall your FF browser and download FF between V-41.0 or V-46.0.

You can download from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox)

Comment: @PavanKumar are you talking about Selenium with Java?  OP is using C#

Comment: Yes. But jar file is same for all languages. Recently they updated jar file from selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar to selenium-server-standalone- 3.0.0-beta2. May be latest version would supports for FF latest versions.@Malachi